# Set Interval() and ClearInterval() logic support

Tags: javascript, html, function, setinterval, clearinterval

having difficulty stopping timer outside of loop. I don't really know why the setTimeout() has been helping the function work... and i know its not the most syntactically correct.. but wondering if someone can help point me as to how to be able to call it outside the function to stop the countdown, say if an action occurs before the timer, and want to call a stopCountdown() function?

```
function countdown(start){
    setTimeout(setCountdown, 1000);
    let startingMinutes = timerEl.innerHTML;
    startingMinutes = start;
    let time = startingMinutes * 60;
    function setCountdown(){
        const minutes = Math.floor(time/60);
        let seconds = time % 60;
         if(seconds < 10){
            seconds = '0' + seconds
         } else {
            seconds
            }
        if(minutes <=0 && seconds <=0){
           clearInterval(start);
            console.log('timerOver')
         } else{
        setTimeout(setCountdown, 1000);  
        timerEl.innerHTML = (minutes + ':'+seconds)
        time--;
        }
    }}

function stopCountdown(){
    document.querySelector("#countdown").innerText = '0'
    setTimeout(setCountdown(start));
}
```

Comment: First I would suggest `const id = setInterval(setCountdown, 1000);` instead of repeated `setTimeout`s. Then, your `countdown` function can `return id;`, passing the interval ID to the calling code. You can then call `clearInterval` with that ID to cancel the countdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to coding, I am trying my best to explain it. First, let me point out some of my opinion on your code

```
function countdown(start){
    setTimeout(setCountdown, 1000);
    let startingMinutes = timerEl.innerHTML;
    startingMinutes = start;
    // I am not sure why you firstly initializing startMinutes
   // to the value of timerEl.innerHTML 
  //and then reassign the value of startMinutes to variable start next line 
    let time = startingMinutes * 60;
    function setCountdown(){
        const minutes = Math.floor(time/60);
        let seconds = time % 60;
         if(seconds < 10){
            seconds = '0' + seconds
         } else {
            seconds
            }
        if(minutes <=0 && seconds <=0){
           clearInterval(start); // you are using setTimeout, not setInterval
            console.log('timerOver')
         } else{
        setTimeout(setCountdown, 1000);  
        timerEl.innerHTML = (minutes + ':'+seconds)
        time--;
        }
    }}

function stopCountdown(){
    document.querySelector("#countdown").innerText = '0'
    setTimeout(setCountdown(start)); 
    // when calling stopCountdown(), what is the value of start? 
    // you can't access function setCountdown inside function stopCountdown

}
```

If my guess is correct, you want to make a timer and then you can make it stop when calling a stopCountdown function, right?
For a timer, it is simply asking javascript to - 1 seconds for every 1000 ms passed. So we can write a function which -1 seconds and ask JS to run it every 1000ms, right?

In this case, you should use setInterval but not setTimeout (setTimeout can also make a timer, I will also show you). The difference is that setTimeout calls a function ONCE after X milliseconds and setInterval will run a function EVERY X milliseconds.

Here is the code

```
let countdownIntervalId // get the countdownIntervalId outside by first declearing a variable to catch the id

function countdown(start) {     // assume the unit of start is minute
    console.log("countdown called, minutes =" + start)
    // add code here to change the innerHTML of the timer if you want
    let secondsToCount = start * 60; //Converting minutes to seconds

    countdownIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
        timer()
    }, 1000); // starting to count down 


    function timer() { // run every seconds
        const minutes = Math.floor(secondsToCount / 60);
        let seconds = secondsToCount - minutes*60;
        console.log("counter= " + minutes + ':' + `${seconds}`.padStart(2, '0'))
        secondsToCount = secondsToCount-1;
        if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownIntervalId); // clearInterval
            console.log('timerOver')
        } 
    }
}

function stopCountdownOutside(){
    if(countdownIntervalId){
        clearInterval(countdownIntervalId)
    }
}

countdown(2) //countdown 2 mins
```

You can stop the counter by calling stopCountdownOutside(), you can test on Chrome console. This is because we are passing the intervalId to the countdownIntervalId which is declare outside the function. so we can simply call clearInterval(countdownIntervalId) to stop it

For using the setTimeout

```
let countdownTimeoutId// get the countdownIntervalId outside by first declearing a variable to catch the id

function countdown(start) {     // assume the unit of start is minute
    console.log("countdown called, minutes =" + start)
    // add code here to change the innerHTML of the timer if you want
    let secondsToCount = start * 60; //Converting minutes to seconds

    countdownTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        timer()
    }, 1000); // starting to count down 


    function timer() { // run every seconds
        const minutes = Math.floor(secondsToCount / 60);
        let seconds = secondsToCount - minutes*60;
        console.log("counter= " + minutes + ':' + `${seconds}`.padStart(2, '0'))
        secondsToCount = secondsToCount-1;
        if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(countdownTimeoutId); // clearTimeout
            console.log('timerOver')
        }else{
            countdownTimeoutId = setTimeout(timer,1000)
        }
    }
}

function stopCountdownOutside(){
    if(countdownTimeoutId){
        clearTimeout(countdownTimeoutId)
    }
}

countdown(1) //countdown 2 mins
```

you can try to refactor my code to a more clean version, happy coding

Comment: these have both been incredibly helpful, thank you!!! I'm going to fuss around with it and dissect it :)